# A design for a poem to be printed on a mug using thermosensitive ink

Tags: design-principles, designers

[image]

**I envy the cup of coffee that gets to kiss your sleepy lips awake every cold and bitter morning**

This particular design (words) will be put as a photo in a mug which I will be gifting to my beloved. This mug will be printed with thermo (heat) sensitive color which will be translucent black in normal condition, but when hot coffee (liquid) is poured into it, the designed text will be shown. For reference [here](http://www.snapfish.co.uk/snapfishuk/gifts/product=photo-magicmug) is the mug in question.

Comment: @Amphiteóth thanks for the clarification. That makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

In light of the holiday spirit I will assist you but I will not create it for you.  If you need help beyond what I am posting then you will need to edit your question with details of what you've tried and I will be happy to open this question back up and allow others to assist you further.  Please do not request for help in the comments and do not make any further questions but go to the edit button and add more information.

What I would suggest:

- Download [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) or [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org/en/)
- Go to the site where you plan on getting it printed and look at the specs.  I am using [VistaPrint](http://www.vistaprint.com/personalized-mugs.aspx?txi=15095&xnav=swsProductOnly_Related) as an example.  Per the documentation I will need to create a document `3.15" x 3.15"` @ 300dpi:

[image]

If I want to know further on what I need in regards to what is acceptable for delivery I will go to there [Formats page](http://www.vistaprint.com/vp/ns/propath/UploadResources.aspx?selectedTab=0%3Fpfid%3DA0Y&pf_id=A0Y&xnav=product-page&pfid=A0Y#DocumentSize).

- After creating the document and reading the documentation I do not need to create guides for the bleed:

[image]

- Since this is supposed to be elegant I would suggest using a script or handwritten font.

To find a good font I would suggest navigating to [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).  Look on the side of font squirrel and you can cycle through the font list:

[image]

- Type in text on the document you've created and experiment with the placement, position, how many lines, etc. etc.  For this amount of text I would experiment with two or three lines but that would depend on the font.

Hope that is helpful  If you need any further assistance please edit the **question** and not add it within the comments.